# Speeding up the pixel by pixel operations on the image

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython, distributed-computing, numba

I am trying to perform pixel by pixel operations on the image but it is painfully slow. It is taking 7-8 hours for a single image of dimension(512*512) and I have images upto 2048*2048.

I have also tried it optimising using **Numba** but it is taking the same time due to the presence of plenty of `pyobjects` which is according to [this](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/09/21/numba-series-part-1-the-jit-decorator-and-some-more-numba-basics.html) tutorial is bad as numba is not able to translate the variables into something it understands and hence optimise.

Below is the short version of my question, I have enclosed the complete details 
So, now I am trying to use cython by following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/28/fast-optimized-for-pixel-loops-with-opencv-and-python/) 
tutorial.
Following is my code, which I am trying to optimise-

```
img = Image.open(path_dir)
pixelMap = img.load()
roi = []
for i in range(img.size[0]):
    for j in range(img.size[1]):
        if pix[i,j] == 255:
            roi.append([i,j])

notroi = img.size[0]*img.size[1] - len(roi)
```

Above this, it doesn't take much time and I don't need to modify it.

```
def roifun(img,roi,notroi,newmap,pix):
    while(notroi):
        border_pixels = []
        h = img.size[0]
        w = img.size[1]
        for i in range(0,h):    //---1
            for j in range(0,w):
                if [i,j] not in roi and ([i+1, j] in roi or [i-1, j] in roi or [i, j+1] in roi or [i, j-1] in roi):
                    border_pixels.append([i,j])
        for (each_i,each_j) in border_pixels: //---2
            color_sum = 0
            count = 1
            eight_neighbourhood = [[each_i-1,each_j],[each_i+1,each_j],[each_i,each_j-1],[each_i,each_j+1],[each_i-1,each_j-1],[each_i-1,each_j+1],[each_i+1,each_j-1],[each_i+1,each_j+1]]
            for pix_i,pix_j in eight_neighbourhood:
                if (pix_i,pix_j) in roi:
                    color_sum+=pix[pix_i,pix_j]
                    count+=1
            newmap[each_i,each_j]=(color_sum//count)

        for (i,j) in border_pixels: //----3
            roi.append([i,j])
            border_pixels.remove([i,j])
            notroi = notroi-1
            print(notroi)
```

Now, I just broke the problem of converting the above code to cython in 3 parts(according to their for loops) for easy debugging.

I converted the first loop in the following way-

```
%%cython -a
import cython
cimport numpy as np
# @cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef border(img,roi):
    border_pixels = []
    cdef long h,w,i,j
    h = img.shape[0]
    w = img.shape[1]
    for i in range(0,h):
        for j in range(0,w):
            if [i,j] not in roi and ([i+1, j] in roi or [i-1, j] in roi or [i, j+1] in roi or [i, j-1] in roi):
                border_pixels.append([i,j])
```

Issue I faced-

1)Getting `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'` while calling the `border` function.
I don't know why it expects the list to be in `byte like object` and how to do it.

2)I don't know how to convert the image in cython way, I tried converting it into `char[:,:]` but then got the error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'GIFImageFile`.

In the second loop, I'll have the same problem but now I have to also try to convert `pix` which is a `pixel object`.

In case, if you guys are wondering what I am trying to achieve, complete details are in this question.
[Expanding the Region of interest of an image](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230044/expanding-the-region-of-interest-of-an-image?noredirect=1#comment449319_230044)

Any other way without cython is also appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the mask image you have included in the linked question, is it supposed to be grayscale or color? When you create your `roi` list, it looks like you are assuming that the data at a given pixel is a single `uint8_t` value rather than an rgba or rgb tuple of data. Are you only considering white pixels as being part of the roi, or just any non-black pixel?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon, yes it is supposed to be color but my first intention to make it fast though how to make it work on actual image, I have yet to figure it out, though if you know any approach then please share

Comment: I have got the approach working right in terms of speed; but I am not sure that the resulting images are right. I can post what code I have in the meantime if that helps.

Comment: Yes, please if you could and you could post it as an answer in the last question's link.

Comment: Okay posted here by accident. I have deleted it and moved my answer to the linked question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely look into using [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) or at least using numpy for anything where you need to process pixels in an image. It will take way too long in pure python.

To reproduce your first bit of code with skimage, I would do this:

```
from skimage import io

img = io.imread(path_dir)
mask = img == 255
```

This will give you a numpy array of True/False values where the pixels are equal to 255. Then you could dilate that mask to get an expanded region of interest.

Comment: I'll try the skimage and then I'll update you.Thanks.